# Payflow and Magento2.4.2 paypal/transparent/redirect 404 error

Tags: magento2, checkout, paypal-payflow-pro

Is it samesite cookies that could be causing this issue?

In issues Chrome:inspect/ it has 10 complaints. Here is the first one, then in another window there are 9 -9 cookies 1 request

1 cookie
Name    Domain & Path
_nx-nocache example.com/
1 request
redirect/

Our site uses Payflow, we have just upgraded to MAG 2.4.2, everything works except Credit Cards using PayFlow. When you select CC and submit payment the page never returns.

First return,

Request URL: https://payflowlink.paypal.com/
Request Method: POST
Status Code: 200 OK

Then another return for the CSS which is OK.

Request URL: https://payflowlink.paypal.com/stylesheet/payflow-table-default.css
Request Method: GET
Status Code: 200 OK (from disk cache)
Remote Address: 173.0.82.48:443
Referrer Policy: strict-origin-when-cross-origin

Now the redirect link,

Request URL: https://example.com/paypal/transparent/redirect/
Request Method: POST
Status Code: 302
Remote Address: 8.29.155.54:443
Referrer Policy: strict-origin-when-cross-origin

The redirect link is in the return,

content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
date: Sun, 18 Jul 2021 13:57:08 GMT
expires: Sat, 18 Jul 2020 13:57:08 GMT
location: https://example.com/stores/store/redirect/?___store=canada&___from_store=default&___store=canada&uenc=aHR0cHM6Ly9zdG9yZS5xa2l0cy5jb20vcGF5cGFsL3RyYW5zcGFyZW50L3JlZGlyZWN0Lz9fX19zdG9yZT1jYW5hZGEmX19fZnJvbV9zdG9yZT1kZWZhdWx0
pragma: no-cache

Then the next response

Request URL: https://example.com/paypal/transparent/redirect/
Request Method: GET
Status Code: 404
Remote Address: 8.29.155.54:443
Referrer Policy: strict-origin-when-cross-origin

content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
date: Sun, 18 Jul 2021 13:57:08 GMT
expires: Fri, 17 Jul 2020 20:16:03 GMT
pragma: no-cache
report-to: {"group":"report-endpoint","max_age":10886400,"endpoints":[{"url":"https://devserver.report-uri.com/r/d/csp/reportOnly"}]}
server: nginx
set-cookie: mffirstvis=1; expires=Mon, 18-Jul-2022 13:57:08 GMT; Max-Age=31536000; path=/; HttpOnly; SameSite=Lax
set-cookie: X-Magento-Vary=5046ceadbafdffb5726c80c2dcf7df07f056ce9c; expires=Mon, 19-Jul-2021 18:43:48 GMT; Max-Age=103600; path=/; secure; HttpOnly; SameSite=Lax
vary: Accept-Encoding
x-content-type-options: nosniff
x-frame-options: SAMEORIGIN
x-xss-protection: 1; mode=block
:authority: store.qkits.com
:method: GET
:path: /paypal/transparent/redirect/
:scheme: https
accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9
accept-encoding: gzip, deflate, br
accept-language: en-US,en;q=0.9
cache-control: max-age=0
referer: https://payflowlink.paypal.com/
sec-ch-ua: " Not;A Brand";v="99", "Google Chrome";v="91", "Chromium";v="91"
sec-ch-ua-mobile: ?0
sec-fetch-dest: iframe
sec-fetch-mode: navigate
sec-fetch-site: cross-site
upgrade-insecure-requests: 1
user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/91.0.4472.164 Safari/537.36

Does anyone know why I am getting a 404 error for the redirect?

Thank you for any help you can offer, this should be the easiest part of the process.

Answer (score 0):

Under store switcher there is a location to include pages the store switcher should not interfere with, adding paypal/* made it so the silent redirect paypal/transparent/redirect/ did not have the store information included in its response, which is what was causing the page to hang indefinitely, have 5 redirects in a row and then nothing just a spinning box. Man that took a while to figure out. Have a great day everyone, if you don't play a sport, be one.

Answer (score 0):

Glad you got it sorted and thank you for posting the solution. I have a strange question- we are in the last stages of finishing out Magento 2 upgrade and, as part of that, implementing transparent redirect. The problem is that, it seems to be very difficult to find out what this transparent redirect looks like "in the wild". The solution my developers have up in the beta site does not look to me like the way the TD solution should work- it has a PayPal pop-up window, and I was under the impression that ideally should not be the case. Do you happen to have a live website with TD implemented that we could look at to see what we should be aiming for?

Answer (score 0):

Where can I find the store switcher tab in Magento 2 ?

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/208663)